# Fragment Shared Element Transitions FragmentManager with add() not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions, fragmentmanager, shared-element-transition

When I tried to use transitions with fragments using similar code from this [article on Medium](https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb)  [GitHub](https://github.com/bherbst/FragmentTransitionSample). It wouldn't work when I am using the add method() on fragment manager but it would work with replace().

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .addSharedElement(mSharedElement, "transName")
            .add(D.id.content_frame, fragment, FRAG_NAME)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

I need to use add() method to keep the fragment below as the user will be navigating back and forth between the first fragment which contains a list of items and the second fragment show detailed info about the item. I don't want to keep loading the fragment with the list again.

Is there a way to get shared element transitions to work when using add() on the fragment manager, than replace().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shared element transition works with FragmentTransaction.replace() but doesn't work with FragmentTransaction.add()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145031/shared-element-transition-works-with-fragmenttransaction-replace-but-doesnt-w)